# Explosion of a projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, explosions

The question is as follows:

> A projectile is moving at 20 m/s at its highest point, where it breaks into equal parts due to an internal explosion. One part moves vertically up at 30 m/s with respect to he ground. Then the other part will move at:

Now this is a simple momentum conservation problem but I had a doubt on how can we find the velocity of second mass in the  direction by applying conservation of momentum in the $y$ direction.

Isn't there an external force gravity acting on the system ? I understand that the explosion force is internal so momentum conservation can be applied in $x$ direction

Comment: I think you should just use conservation of momentum, and the velocity and direction of the second part after the explosion, before g changes both velocities ,

Comment: Trula is correct. Consider the momentum just prior to and immediately following the explosion.

Comment: Of course, the mass and momentum of the gases resulting from the explosion are  conveniently ignored...

Comment: Ok thanks that answers my question. I was thinking the book authors neglected gravity as compared to the explosion forces(considering them to be way more than gravity) so momentum could be conserved . That cleared my concept

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the accepted answer?

Comment: I don't know , that's the reason I asked the question. But I think so trula's  answer is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't there an external force gravity acting on the system ?

Correct.  And the momentum change from a force is $\Delta p = Ft$.  The smaller the time the force is acting, the smaller the momentum change.

For this class of problems, you can assume the explosion takes an arbitrarily small amount of time.  If the "before explosion" and "after explosion" is very close together, then the momentum change of gravity can be ignored for that interval.

Answer (score -1):

You need to consider conservation of momentum in both the horizontal and vertical directions.

Comment: I don't think this quite answers the question.  The OP is asking why the momentum is conserved in the vertical direction during the explosion, even though there's a downward force acting on the projectile.

Comment: See the answer from "BowlOfRed".